# Using "this" - many instances of class, calling private method

Tags: c#

I have a server where every connected client is represented by an instance of client class. This class is responsible for data processing. I always thought that when calling private function even when there are more instances of the same class, I dont need to use "this" keyword because its considered as local call, also:

```
if (data[1]==2 && data [3]==2)
   SendAck();
```

But when there were more players (more client classes), sometimes the message was sent to another player and the same with other methods. All was OK when I added "this" to all methods call. Is it possible that wihout "this" it calls method from some other class?
Thanks!

EDITL: What about using public members like public dictionary in each instance and then not using this keyword /like when calling TryGetValue/?

Comment: 1. Are you possibly calling a static method?

Comment: Take away your 'this's and run some tests - is the sometimes behaviour consistent and repeatable?  What is common amongst the places where this behaviour occurs?

Comment: No, it was very random and rare problem.

Answer (score 3):

No, this isn't possible. "this" is almost all of the time optional. A situation where you would need it would be if you have a method (for example your constructor) that takes parameters of the same name than fields of your class and you want to assign the values of these parameters to the fields, eg:

```
class Test
{
    private string strValue;

    public Test(string strValue)
    {
        this.strValue = strValue;
    }
}
```

I thinks there is another problem in your code. Could you please give more details?

Comment: Maybe its because some methods are public?

Comment: No. The public / private qualifiers have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Sorry I cannot give you more details, its pretty complex app and when I added this keyword to some method calls, all problems suddenly stopped. It was like method from different instance of class was executed.

Comment: Could it be that there are static members in your class that have the same name than instance members and have the same number of parameters with less derived parameter types? In this case, a call without "this" would call the static member.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any difference between `SendAck();` and `this.SendAck();`, if the method is a member of your class. You will always call the method from the instance that is calling the method.

Check what the method actually does when called, using the debugger. You will see that it is the same method, with or without the `this` keyword.

Comment: this.SendAck() can be extensions method call (synaxical sugar for that particular class)

Comment: Still, if there is a `SendAck` method in the current class, both `SendAck()` and `this.SendAck()` will call *that* method, because it has priority over extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

From C# Specification:

> 7.5.7 This access
>
> …
>   When this is used in a primary-expression within an
>   instance method or instance accessor
>   of a class, it is  classified as a
>   value. The type of the value is the
>   instance type (§10.3.1) of the class
>   within which the usage  occurs, and
>   the **value is a reference to the object
>   for which the method or accessor was
>   invoked.**

I suspect that you have problems with multithreaded access to instances of type that represent connected clients.

Comment: There is threadpool so this should not be a problem. And what about public mewmbers<

Comment: Presense of a threadpool by itself doesn't guarantee that access to shared state is safe. Excerpt above is true for all instance (with whatever accessibility) methods and accessors.